# Collection of Browser characteristics

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, google-chrome, opera

I searching the Internet for an Page or an Book that collects the characteristics (Bugs/Features) of common Browsers. I get a lot of Information from several sites.. but is there some place for webdesigner that focusses on that issue?

At the moment i am using Grails if that is an needed factor to answer my question.

Comment: check this as well, basically all bugs you would need to know about with test demos, very usefull http://www.brunildo.org/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is pretty good for listing browser bugs and compatibility.

[Sitepoint's reference section](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) is also pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I know is this excellent guide on Browser security. It also has a comparison of various browser features. Go through the 1 & 2 parts at least.

http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2

I think a better approach for you should be to:

- review standards supported by various
  browser
- testing your app on browser and making appropriate changes

Comment: i already test my apps on different Browsers. I use alot Conditional Comments. But it is a lot of trial and error. I always find an solution by google around or fixing it by myself. From my point of view a lot of people fixing such issues every day. So there is colletion? :-)

Comment: oh and by the way...thank you for that useful link. Nice Information there.

Comment: I don't think there is such a collection. 

Think of it. If one were to write such a note, describing how the different HTML tags are to be rendered will itself run into 1000s of pages. Leave alone script, css, media...

I think browser testing is your best bet.