# Background Color - for IE6, IE7

Tags: html, css

**Works in IE8 & Mozilla**

```
select:focus, input:focus,textarea:focus
{
    background:#abd533;
    font-family:verdana;
}
```

While using IE7,  I observed that input field background color not shown, but it appears in IE8 & Mozilla.

Can anyone please let me know what to do with IE7 or IE6 ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in IE7

See

[Basic Selector Support Tests](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=IE7)

You can use javascript to detect focus and change the class name.

Answer (score 0):

i would to show you this link. It deals with a lot of browser issues:

http://quirksmode.org is pretty good for listing browser bugs and compatibility.

Taken from my question:

[Collection of Browser characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346094/collection-of-browser-characteristics)

Just want to add this cause this sites helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've encountered one of Internet Explorer's (many) bugs.

For IE6 and 5, this page is quite useful for form control styling: [Styling Form Controls](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200409/styling_form_controls/)